# How to reach all input field values and submit with button in form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What I want to do is simple, just take input field values and do something with them by clicking button.

```
function TableFooterPanel() {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const sampleMethod = (x, y) => {
        console.log(x + y)
    }

    return (

        <>
            <Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onClick={setFirstName}></input>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onClick={setLastName}></input>
                    <Button onClick={() => sampleMethod(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>

        </>

    );

}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

Generally examples for that is done with separate handleChange() methods for each input field but I don't want to make separate functions for each so I though to use useState. How can I call the sampleMethod with these parameters ? I could not update values properly with useState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use input field as text, you need onChange :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
```

That way the text that you typing in the input will save in the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Another suggestion from me is to add an onSubmit event to the form. It's more convenient.

The button should be `type="submit"`. When the user clicks on it the form's `onSubmit` event will fire.